# DocuSign Branding: Merge field [[SenderAccount]] not being populated properly in DS prod system (but works fine in demo)

Tags: docusignapi

The merge field [[SenderAccount]] is not being populated properly in the DocuSign production environment (but it is doing the correct thing in the demo environment).  At one time, this worked ok in production, and my resource files in PROD vs DEMO are identical, so I am inclined to think there is a code difference in the DS environments.

We are using the DocuSign API to both initialize/update the brand resource files as well as for creating and sending envelopes.  Our custom resource files uploaded for our brands are essentially identical, representing some customization to the DocuSign master resource files of content and appearance of various aspects of the signing experience.  The one causing a problem is the 'DocuSign_IntroAgree' data element.  My resource file sets this data element value to:

```
"I agree to do business electronically with [[SenderAccount]]"
```

In the demo environment, the value for [[SenderAccount]] is properly being populated with information from my brand.  In production, however, it is being populated with information from my account (my company name).

I have verified that other aspects of the signing experience are pulling from the correct brand (logos, for example), so it doesn't appear to be a problem with finding the brand.

As I mentioned, this has worked in the past.  We just noticed it today, but it could have been an issue for some time.

Is there a known difference in the behavior on the DS demo and prod environments with respect to this issue?  Or does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: I know there was some patch work done in this area specifically, and it is intended to 'work'. Are you on NA1 or NA2 for PROD? If you have not already done so, please submit a ticket to DocuSign support through your standard channels.

Comment: I think I'm on 'NA1' but I'm not 100% sure I'm looking at the right thing to determine that.  I have entered a support ticket.

Comment: @rickus123 in your Prod account under Preferences > Electronic Record and Signature Disclosure do you have "Use brand company name" enabled? If that is not enabled, DocuSign will always pull your Account Name value for [[SenderAccount]] not your Brand Company Name. This switch can alternatively pull your Membership Company Name value if in your Brand > Info Tab you *also* have "Use the membership company name" enabled. Is this the difference b/t your Demo and Prod accounts causing this issue?

Comment: That was it.  Our demo config had that option checked, but it was not checked in prod.  I thought this was working in prod at one time in the past, but apparently not or maybe something in DocuSign land altered our setting but that seems unlikely).  Thanks for your help -- enter this as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @rickus123. I've gone ahead and added my answer along with some screens and links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Preferences > Electronic Record and Signature Disclosure you must have "Use brand company name" enabled.
[image]

If that is not enabled, DocuSign will always pull your Account Name value for [[SenderAccount]] not your Brand Company Name. This switch can alternatively pull your Membership Company Name value if in your Brand > Info Tab you also have "Use the membership company name" enabled.

[image]

See the [Electronic Record and Signature Disclosure Documentation](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-admin-guide-electronic-record-and-signature-disclosure) and the [DocuSign Custom Account Branding Guide](https://08d1d92f490618f41c65-8fb00e97ac499a7066a18ce9c66b019b.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/Quick_Start_-_Account_Branding.pdf)